# how to fire only the very last setTimeout

Tags: javascript

```
window.addEventListener('resize', onResize, false);
function onResize() {
    timer = setTimeout(function() { 
        console.log('fire timer');
    }, 1000);
}
```

Resize event fires super fast. So there will be many timer fire every 1000ms. How to fire only the very last timer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Clear the timer for each call

```
var timer;

function onResize() {

    clearTimeout(timer);

    //...

    timer = setTimeout(function() { 
        console.log('fire timer');
    }, 1000);
}
```

(`timer` may be null or undefined).

Answer (score 2):

If you're already using underscore.js, you have the [debounce](http://underscorejs.org/#debounce) method to fill this need:

> Creates and returns a new debounced version of the passed function that will postpone its execution until after wait milliseconds have elapsed since the last time it was invoked. Useful for implementing behavior that should only happen *after* the input has stopped arriving.